# Expectation of random vectors

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm studying probability for preparing myself for machine learning. And I don't understand how to get the expectation of that : $E(w^TX)$ where $w$ is a random vector and $X \sim N(0,1)$. Can anybody explain me how I can calculate the value of this expression.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand the product and use the property

$$
\mathbb{E}[a X + bY] = a\mathbb{E}[X] + b\mathbb{E}[Y] 
$$

Therefore

$$
\mathbb{E}[w^TX] = \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_k w_k X_k\right] = \sum_k w_k\underbrace{\mathbb{E}[X_k]}_{=0} = 0
$$

The last term comes from the fact that $X_k\sim N(0, 1)$